# What Is the Laplace Transform of $\frac{\partial{\phi}}{\partial{t}} = \frac{\partial^2{\phi}}{\partial{x}^2} - \cos(x)$, where $\phi = \phi(x, t)$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I was wondering what the Laplace transform of $\dfrac{\partial{\phi}}{\partial{t}} = \dfrac{\partial^2{\phi}}{\partial{x}^2} - \cos(x)$, where $\phi = \phi(x, t)$, is?

I know the Laplace transform of $\dfrac{\partial{\phi}}{\partial{t}}$ is $s \mathcal{L}\{ \phi \} - \phi(0)$, but I'm not sure what it is for the second part, since $\dfrac{\partial^2{\phi}}{\partial{x}^2}$ is the derivative with respect to $x$ and $\cos(x)$ is a function of $x$?

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: No `\dfrac` in titles, thanks.

Comment: @Did Arg, I keep copy and pasting into the titles, and forget that it includes `\dfrac`. Sorry again...

Comment: @Nosrati Are you sure? This is different from Aleksas Domarkas's answer?

Comment: @Nosrati But it is taking the second derivative with respect to $x$ instead of $t$. Does this change anything, since the Laplace transform is applied to functions of $t$?

Answer (score 1):

We get
$$s \mathcal{L}\{ \phi \} - \phi(0)=\frac{d^2}{d {x^2}}\mathcal{L}\{ \phi \}-\frac{\cos x}{s}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please explain why (explain reasoning).

Comment: And why did it change from partial derivative $\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial{x}^2}$ to normal derivative $\dfrac{d^2}{d {x^2}}$?

Comment: that follows literally from the definition of the laplace transform @ThePointer

Comment: @DaveNine What do you mean? Can you please show what you mean?